# Encode/Encrypt issue while porting Python to Perl script

Tags: python, perl, encryption, decode, encode

I have a Python script which works fine. It is able decode/decrypt a provided pwd, and encode/encrypt it back, as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from Crypto.Cipher import DES3
import base64

secret = base64.decodestring('tcxpLw1PsMR0CtXt/HfbIZomvJtDyE6h1Gl4vblX2W4=')
key = secret[:24]
iv = secret[24:]

# Encoded Encrypted password
EEpwd = '4TOHTKsvihUXuUd9M3TpoA=='
print "Encoded Encrypted Password : ",EEpwd

# Decoded Encrypted password
DEpwd = base64.decodestring(EEpwd)

# Decoded Decrypted password
DDpwd = DES3.new(key, DES3.MODE_CBC, iv).decrypt(DEpwd)
print "Decoded (Decrypted ( PWD ) ) : ",DDpwd

# New Decoded Encrypted password
NewDEpwd = DES3.new(key, DES3.MODE_CBC, iv).encrypt(DDpwd)

# New Encoded Encrypted password
NewEEpwd = base64.b64encode(NewDEpwd)
print "New Encoded (Encrypted (",DDpwd,") ) : ",NewEEpwd
```

... this gives me the following output:

```
Encoded Encrypted Password :  4TOHTKsvihUXuUd9M3TpoA==
Decoded (Decrypted ( PWD ) ) :  MYweakPW
New Encoded (Encrypted ( MYweakPW ) ) :  4TOHTKsvihUXuUd9M3TpoA==
```

Now I have to migrate this script to Perl, so I did:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use MIME::Base64;
use Crypt::CBC;

$secret = decode_base64('tcxpLw1PsMR0CtXt/HfbIZomvJtDyE6h1Gl4vblX2W4=');
$key = substr($secret,0,24);
$iv = substr($secret,24);

$cipher = Crypt::CBC->new(
                -cipher => 'DES_EDE3',
                -key    => $key,
                -iv     => $iv,
                -header => 'none',
                -padding => 'null',
                -literal_key => 1
                );

# Encoded Encrypted password
$EEpwd = '4TOHTKsvihUXuUd9M3TpoA==';
print "Encoded Encrypted Password : ". $EEpwd ."\n";

# Decoded Encrypted password
$DEpwd = decode_base64($EEpwd);

# Decoded Decrypted password
$DDpwd = $cipher->decrypt($DEpwd);
print "Decoded (Decrypted ( PWD ) ) : $DDpwd \n";

# New Decoded Encrypted password
$NewDEpwd = $cipher->encrypt($DDpwd);

# New Encoded Encrypted password
$NewEEpwd = encode_base64($NewDEpwd);
print "New Encoded (Encrypted ($DDpwd) ) : $NewEEpwd \n";
```

... but this returns to me:

```
Encoded Encrypted Password : 4TOHTKsvihUXuUd9M3TpoA==
Decoded (Decrypted ( PWD ) ) : MYweakPW 
New Encoded (Encrypted (MYweakPW) ) : 4TOHTKsvihU=
```

**Question:** Why when I encrypt/encode the password back in Perl, it returns a shorten string ? What is missing to have that matching ?

Regards
RZ

---

**EDIT**

Since I am changing the accepted answer, let me clarify some aspects of this code usage, to justify some choices.
Of course this is not the entire script. I have removed as much as possible any private info, as well as other pieces of the script that was already working, isolating the piece of code that was requiring attention.
The overall intend of the script is manage passwords used in some others scripts/apps, when the password is changed on the remote servers.

This specific piece of code it handling the password stored by Remmina in the saved sessions. Unfortunately Remmina does not provided a centralized method to replace the saved passwords, so in my case, every time I change my password at Windows domain, all my Remmina saved sessions get outdated (and I have dozens of it!)

The way that Remmina store the passwords are:

- at `$HOME/.remmina/remmina.pref` there are a line containing `secret=*` , encoded, with the DES3 `key` and `iv`
- at each session file, named `$HOME/.remmina/*.remmina` there are a line containing `password=*` with your password, encoded and encrypted

That said, it is irrelevant to say if the original encrypted/encoded password was correctly or incorrectly generated ... That is the way Remmina does it and I have to deal with it :-/

Depending on the parameters provided on the command line, the script should be able to retrieve the stored password from `*.remmina` files, or get a new one and replace that on `*.remmina` files, so the point raised by @jm666 on his EDIT2 is very relevant, as, when I get a new password from command line, it won't be previously padded in any way.

For my particular scenario, I know that passwords will never be shorter then 8 bytes, but can be longer, and not a multiple of 8, so I have tested this with new different passwords, and realized that, to encrypt passwords for Remmina, the appropriate is `padding = 'null'`

- A particular case seems to be when the password have exactly 8 bytes long (or multiples of it). In this case, I had to 'manually' add a single `null` char in the end of the provided string, to force padding add the extra `null` chars

Comment: Its possible that your logic flow is wrong at the end. Try to do the reverse. First convert plain text to base64 and then encrypt it. See if it works first.

Comment: Also, it would be much easier if you would use the word "Plain Text" instead of "Decoded Decrypted Password".

Comment: Not really ... The logic is correct.
As you can see, I used the exact same sequence on Python and Perl, so if the matter were the logic, Python would also fails.
Also, encrypt will certainly give unprinttable chars, which won't happen with encode, so, it need to be first encrypted, and then encoded.

Thanks anyway for your insight

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You asked perl using `padding=>'null'`. Simply change the:

```
$cipher = Crypt::CBC->new(
                -cipher => 'DES_EDE3',
                -key    => $key,
                -iv     => $iv,
                -header => 'none',
                -padding => 'null',
                -literal_key => 1
                );
```

to `-padding => 'none',` and will get the **same result as python**.

**NOTE: The above gives the wanted output, but it is WRONG answer**, as well as @harmic's answer too. See the EDIT2 bellow.

Note, if you didn't enter any paddig, (as you didn't uses any padding in your python code), e.g.

```
$cipher = Crypt::CBC->new(
                -cipher => 'DES_EDE3',
                -key    => $key,
                -iv     => $iv,
                -header => 'none',
                #-padding => 'null',   # <- commented out
                -literal_key => 1
                );
```

perl will use the `standard` padding defined in `PKCS#5`, e.g. padds with the number what is equal to missing padding bytes. e.g. if missing 2 bytes, the padding will be `0x02 0x02` if missing 3 bytes the padding will be `0x03 0x03 0x03`. (therefore will produce different result as python with no defined padding)

### EDIT

from the Changelog of the Crypt::CBC

> ```
> 2.31    Tue Oct 30 07:03:40 EDT 2012
>     - Fixes to regular expressions to avoid rare failures to
>       correctly strip padding in decoded messages.
>     - Add padding type = "none".
>     - Both fixes contributed by Bas van Sisseren.
> ```

The padding `none` is suported nearly two years. :)

## EDIT2

using `none` or `space` is entirely incorrect, because:

You can never get your original `4TOHTKsvihUXuUd9M3TpoA==` encoded string **correctly**.

Try encrypt and encode directly entered password `MYweakPW`.
Regardless of the used padding, you **never** get the original
`4TOHTKsvihUXuUd9M3TpoA==` string.

You will get the next ones (depending on the used padding):

```
Padding: standard               4TOHTKsvihW3UDR8tqmBIg==
Padding: space                  4TOHTKsvihU=
Padding: oneandzeroes           4TOHTKsvihUndO+JKCfmog==
Padding: rijndael_compat        4TOHTKsvihU=
Padding: null                   4TOHTKsvihU=
Padding: none                   4TOHTKsvihU=
```

The plaintext password `MYweakPW` hexdump:

```
4d597765616b5057
```

You, after the `decode -> decrypt` got (depending of the used padding method:)

```
4d597765616b50570000000000000000
#or
4d597765616b5057
```

and when trying encrypt it again, the encrypting algorithm again adds new padding (or not - depending of the used method) to the string.

The whole is can be seen in the following script (mostly yours, only using hexadecimal output):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use MIME::Base64;
use Crypt::CBC;

my $secret = decode_base64('tcxpLw1PsMR0CtXt/HfbIZomvJtDyE6h1Gl4vblX2W4=');
my $iv = substr($secret,24);
my $key = substr($secret,0,24);

for my $padd ( qw(standard space  oneandzeroes  rijndael_compat  null  none)) {
    my $c = Crypt::CBC->new( -cipher=>'DES_EDE3', -key=>$key, -iv=>$iv,
                -header=>'none', -literal_key=>1,
                -padding=>$padd
            );
    print "== Padding: $padd=\n";
    display($c);
}

sub display {
    my $cipher = shift;

    my $EEpwd = '4TOHTKsvihUXuUd9M3TpoA==';
    p("Original (encrypted & encoded)", $EEpwd);

    my $DEpwd = decode_base64($EEpwd);
    ph("Original (decoded still encrypted)", $DEpwd);

    my $DDpwd = $cipher->decrypt($DEpwd);
    ph("Original plaintext", $DDpwd);

    my $NewDEpwd = $cipher->encrypt($DDpwd);
    ph("New from orig (encrypted)", $NewDEpwd);

    my $NewEEpwd = encode_base64($NewDEpwd);
    p( "New from orig (encrypted+encoded)", $NewEEpwd);

    my $asc = "MYweakPW";
    ph("String $asc", $asc);
    my $m1 = $cipher->encrypt($asc);
    ph("String (encrypted)", $m1);
    p("String (encrypted,encoded)", encode_base64($m1));
}

sub ph  { p($_[0] . " hex:", unpack('H*',$_[1]) ) }
sub p   { printf "%40.40s %s\n", @_; }
```

the output, compare youself what hexdump's you got after the decrypt/encrypt depending on used padding. (The "oroginal" mean strings what you get from the original base64 encoded, and the "String" mean value what you get from the directly entered string `MYweakPW`.

```
== Padding: standard=
          Original (encrypted & encoded) 4TOHTKsvihUXuUd9M3TpoA==
 Original (decoded still encrypted) hex: e133874cab2f8a1517b9477d3374e9a0
                 Original plaintext hex: 4d597765616b50570000000000000000
          New from orig (encrypted) hex: e133874cab2f8a1517b9477d3374e9a0a26625e0d2ebb3d4
       New from orig (encrypted+encoded) 4TOHTKsvihUXuUd9M3TpoKJmJeDS67PU

                    String MYweakPW hex: 4d597765616b5057
                 String (encrypted) hex: e133874cab2f8a15b750347cb6a98122
              String (encrypted,encoded) 4TOHTKsvihW3UDR8tqmBIg==

== Padding: space=
          Original (encrypted & encoded) 4TOHTKsvihUXuUd9M3TpoA==
 Original (decoded still encrypted) hex: e133874cab2f8a1517b9477d3374e9a0
                 Original plaintext hex: 4d597765616b50570000000000000000
          New from orig (encrypted) hex: e133874cab2f8a1517b9477d3374e9a0
       New from orig (encrypted+encoded) 4TOHTKsvihUXuUd9M3TpoA==

                    String MYweakPW hex: 4d597765616b5057
                 String (encrypted) hex: e133874cab2f8a15
              String (encrypted,encoded) 4TOHTKsvihU=

== Padding: oneandzeroes=
          Original (encrypted & encoded) 4TOHTKsvihUXuUd9M3TpoA==
 Original (decoded still encrypted) hex: e133874cab2f8a1517b9477d3374e9a0
                 Original plaintext hex: 4d597765616b50570000000000000000
          New from orig (encrypted) hex: e133874cab2f8a1517b9477d3374e9a0854bea98199fa99e
       New from orig (encrypted+encoded) 4TOHTKsvihUXuUd9M3TpoIVL6pgZn6me

                    String MYweakPW hex: 4d597765616b5057
                 String (encrypted) hex: e133874cab2f8a152774ef892827e6a2
              String (encrypted,encoded) 4TOHTKsvihUndO+JKCfmog==

== Padding: rijndael_compat=
          Original (encrypted & encoded) 4TOHTKsvihUXuUd9M3TpoA==
 Original (decoded still encrypted) hex: e133874cab2f8a1517b9477d3374e9a0
                 Original plaintext hex: 4d597765616b50570000000000000000
          New from orig (encrypted) hex: e133874cab2f8a1517b9477d3374e9a0
       New from orig (encrypted+encoded) 4TOHTKsvihUXuUd9M3TpoA==

                    String MYweakPW hex: 4d597765616b5057
                 String (encrypted) hex: e133874cab2f8a15
              String (encrypted,encoded) 4TOHTKsvihU=

== Padding: null=
          Original (encrypted & encoded) 4TOHTKsvihUXuUd9M3TpoA==
 Original (decoded still encrypted) hex: e133874cab2f8a1517b9477d3374e9a0
                 Original plaintext hex: 4d597765616b5057
          New from orig (encrypted) hex: e133874cab2f8a15
       New from orig (encrypted+encoded) 4TOHTKsvihU=

                    String MYweakPW hex: 4d597765616b5057
                 String (encrypted) hex: e133874cab2f8a15
              String (encrypted,encoded) 4TOHTKsvihU=

== Padding: none=
          Original (encrypted & encoded) 4TOHTKsvihUXuUd9M3TpoA==
 Original (decoded still encrypted) hex: e133874cab2f8a1517b9477d3374e9a0
                 Original plaintext hex: 4d597765616b50570000000000000000
          New from orig (encrypted) hex: e133874cab2f8a1517b9477d3374e9a0
       New from orig (encrypted+encoded) 4TOHTKsvihUXuUd9M3TpoA==

                    String MYweakPW hex: 4d597765616b5057
                 String (encrypted) hex: e133874cab2f8a15
              String (encrypted,encoded) 4TOHTKsvihU=
```

The result:

- from the literal string `MYweakPW` (e.g. without the 8 zeroes at it's end) you can never get the wanted output, regardless of the padding (see the results)
- so, you original string `4TOHTKsvihUXuUd9M3TpoA==` was created INCORRECTLY (or deliberately added  eight null characters to the `MYweakPW` what is already 8byte-padded).
- you should re-check how the original string was created (with what padding method) especially with the password what is **not exactly 8 byte long**. E.g. try create the base64 encoded string from the password `weak` and you will see, how it is padded.

Comment: using `-padding => 'none'` I got this error when running:

    'none' padding not supported.  See perldoc Crypt::CBC for instructions on creating your own. at ./dec.pl line 9

... commenting it out, like you show, returned: `4TOHTKsvihUXuUd9M3TpoKJmJeDS67PU`

... it finaly worked with `-padding => 'space'` as suggested by @harmic

Anyway, thanks a lot for your inputs.

Comment: @Renato You have some archaic `Crypt::CBC`. Check here: https://metacpan.org/pod/Crypt::CBC and will see, the `-padding => 'none'` is supported. ;)

Comment: @ jm666 , I agree 110% with you! .. I did checked and the `Crypt::CBC` I have installed is v2.29.  
Anyway, since the solution adding `-padding => 'space'` were able to achieve the desired result, regardless of `Crypt::CBC` version, I consider more appropriate to keep the other solution as the **accepted** one. But once again, thank you so much for your time and insights.

Comment: @Renato bot answers are entirely **WRONG**. Will post the edit soon, what explain why.

Answer (score 3):

The padding option you have chosen would not appear to be the same as the one that the Python encryption library is using.

I found that by changing the -padding option to 'space', the re-encrypted password was the same as the original.

Comment: Thanks @harmic. It worked fine. What I did not understood was why, in the decrypt phase the `padding` made no difference. I was assuming that it was correct, as it was able to decrypt the password perfectly.